# RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered in Automatic1111

Tags: pytorch, stable-diffusion

I have been using Automatic1111 and animatediff + controlnet + Adetailer for txt2img generation. I have been using it for a project for a week and nothing wrong with it. And suddenly few days ago it started to get error, it stopped generating after the Adetailer process. I found out it doesn't work because of Adetailer, it work alright when I disable it but I needed Adetailer so I have been trying to fix it. I tried updating it, doesn't work.
I even tried formating my computer and reinstall everything. Still the same. I am a newbie so please help me out.. thank you very much. This is the error I got:

```
*** Error running postprocess_image: C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\extensions\adetailer\scripts\!adetailer.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\scripts.py", line 856, in postprocess_image
        script.postprocess_image(p, pp, *script_args)
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\extensions\adetailer\adetailer\traceback.py", line 159, in wrapper
        raise error from None
    RuntimeError:
    ╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
    │                                                   System info                                                    │
    │ ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓ │
    │ ┃             ┃ Value                                                                                          ┃ │
    │ ┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩ │
    │ │    Platform │ Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0                                                                      │ │
    │ │      Python │ 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]               │ │
    │ │     Version │ v1.8.0                                                                                         │ │
    │ │      Commit │ bef51aed032c0aaa5cfd80445bc4cf0d85b408b5                                                       │ │
    │ │ Commandline │ ['launch.py', '--no-download-sd-model', '--disable-nan-check', '--skip-version-check',         │ │
    │ │             │ '--no-half-vae', '--upcast-sampling', '--opt-sdp-attention', '--xformers',                     │ │
    │ │             │ '--force-enable-xformers', '--autolaunch']                                                     │ │
    │ │   Libraries │ {'torch': '2.1.2+cu121', 'torchvision': '0.16.2+cu121', 'ultralytics': '8.1.22', 'mediapipe':  │ │
    │ │             │ '0.10.10'}                                                                                     │ │
    │ └─────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │
    │                           Inputs                                                                                 │
    │ ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓                                                      │
    │ ┃                 ┃ Value                                 ┃                                                      │
    │ ┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩                                                      │
    │ │          prompt │ girls runinng                         │                                                      │
    │ │ negative_prompt │                                       │                                                      │
    │ │          n_iter │ 1                                     │                                                      │
    │ │      batch_size │ 16                                    │                                                      │
    │ │           width │ 512                                   │                                                      │
    │ │          height │ 512                                   │                                                      │
    │ │    sampler_name │ DPM++ 2M Karras                       │                                                      │
    │ │       enable_hr │ False                                 │                                                      │
    │ │     hr_upscaler │ Latent                                │                                                      │
    │ │      checkpoint │ Dreamshaper8.safetensors [879db523c3] │                                                      │
    │ │             vae │ Automatic                             │                                                      │
    │ │            unet │ Automatic                             │                                                      │
    │ └─────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────┘                                                      │
    │                 ADetailer                                                                                        │
    │ ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓                                                                        │
    │ ┃                     ┃ Value           ┃                                                                        │
    │ ┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩                                                                        │
    │ │             version │ 24.3.0          │                                                                        │
    │ │            ad_model │ face_yolov8n.pt │                                                                        │
    │ │           ad_prompt │                 │                                                                        │
    │ │  ad_negative_prompt │                 │                                                                        │
    │ │ ad_controlnet_model │ None            │                                                                        │
    │ │              is_api │ False           │                                                                        │
    │ └─────────────────────┴─────────────────┘                                                                        │
    │ ╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\extensions\adetailer\adetailer\traceback.py:139 in       │             │
    │ │ wrapper                                                                                          │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   138 │   │   try:                                                                               │             │
    │ │ ❱ 139 │   │   │   return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                   │             │
    │ │   140 │   │   except Exception as e:                                                             │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\extensions\adetailer\scripts\!adetailer.py:778 in        │             │
    │ │ postprocess_image                                                                                │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │    777 │   │   │   │   │   continue                                                              │             │
    │ │ ❱  778 │   │   │   │   is_processed |= self._postprocess_image_inner(p, pp, args, n=n)           │             │
    │ │    779                                                                                           │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\extensions\adetailer\scripts\!adetailer.py:701 in        │             │
    │ │ _postprocess_image_inner                                                                         │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │    700 │   │   with change_torch_load():                                                         │             │
    │ │ ❱  701 │   │   │   pred = predictor(ad_model, pp.image, args.ad_confidence, **kwargs)            │             │
    │ │    702                                                                                           │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\extensions\adetailer\adetailer\ultralytics.py:29 in      │             │
    │ │ ultralytics_predict                                                                              │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   28 │   apply_classes(model, model_path, classes)                                               │             │
    │ │ ❱ 29 │   pred = model(image, conf=confidence, device=device)                                     │             │
    │ │   30                                                                                             │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py:16 │             │
    │ │ 9 in __call__                                                                                    │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   168 │   │   """                                                                                │             │
    │ │ ❱ 169 │   │   return self.predict(source, stream, **kwargs)                                      │             │
    │ │   170                                                                                            │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py:43 │             │
    │ │ 2 in predict                                                                                     │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   431 │   │   │   self.predictor = predictor or self._smart_load("predictor")(overrides=args,    │             │
    │ │ ❱ 432 │   │   │   self.predictor.setup_model(model=self.model, verbose=is_cli)                   │             │
    │ │   433 │   │   else:  # only update args if predictor is already setup                            │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.p │             │
    │ │ y:343 in setup_model                                                                             │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   342 │   │   """Initialize YOLO model with given parameters and set it to evaluation mode."""   │             │
    │ │ ❱ 343 │   │   self.model = AutoBackend(                                                          │             │
    │ │   344 │   │   │   model or self.args.model,                                                      │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py:115 │             │
    │ │ in decorate_context                                                                              │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   114 │   │   with ctx_factory():                                                                │             │
    │ │ ❱ 115 │   │   │   return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                   │             │
    │ │   116                                                                                            │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\autobackend.py: │             │
    │ │ 140 in __init__                                                                                  │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   139 │   │   if nn_module:  # in-memory PyTorch model                                           │             │
    │ │ ❱ 140 │   │   │   model = weights.to(device)                                                     │             │
    │ │   141 │   │   │   model = model.fuse(verbose=verbose) if fuse else model                         │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:116 │             │
    │ │ 0 in to                                                                                          │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   1159 │   │                                                                                     │             │
    │ │ ❱ 1160 │   │   return self._apply(convert)                                                       │             │
    │ │   1161                                                                                           │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\tasks.py:226 in │             │
    │ │ _apply                                                                                           │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │    225 │   │   """                                                                               │             │
    │ │ ❱  226 │   │   self = super()._apply(fn)                                                         │             │
    │ │    227 │   │   m = self.model[-1]  # Detect()                                                    │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:810 │             │
    │ │ in _apply                                                                                        │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │    809 │   │   │   for module in self.children():                                                │             │
    │ │ ❱  810 │   │   │   │   module._apply(fn)                                                         │             │
    │ │    811                                                                                           │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:810 │             │
    │ │ in _apply                                                                                        │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │    809 │   │   │   for module in self.children():                                                │             │
    │ │ ❱  810 │   │   │   │   module._apply(fn)                                                         │             │
    │ │    811                                                                                           │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:810 │             │
    │ │ in _apply                                                                                        │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │    809 │   │   │   for module in self.children():                                                │             │
    │ │ ❱  810 │   │   │   │   module._apply(fn)                                                         │             │
    │ │    811                                                                                           │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:833 │             │
    │ │ in _apply                                                                                        │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │    832 │   │   │   with torch.no_grad():                                                         │             │
    │ │ ❱  833 │   │   │   │   param_applied = fn(param)                                                 │             │
    │ │    834 │   │   │   should_use_set_data = compute_should_use_set_data(param, param_applied)       │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │ C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:115 │             │
    │ │ 8 in convert                                                                                     │             │
    │ │                                                                                                  │             │
    │ │   1157 │   │   │   │   │   │   │   non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)                │             │
    │ │ ❱ 1158 │   │   │   return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else No  │             │
    │ │   1159                                                                                           │             │
    │ ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯             │
    │ RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered                                                           │
    │ Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.                                              │
    │                                                                                                                  │
    ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯


---
*** Error completing request
*** Arguments: ('task(nhh84s7w8xorjgy)', <gradio.routes.Request object at 0x000001F95012BCD0>, 'girls runinng', '', [], 20, 'DPM++ 2M Karras', 1, 1, 7, 512, 512, False, 0.7, 2, 'Latent', 0, 0, 0, 'Use same checkpoint', 'Use same sampler', '', '', [], 0, False, '', 0.8, -1, False, -1, 0, 0, 0, True, False, {'ad_model': 'face_yolov8n.pt', 'ad_model_classes': '', 'ad_prompt': '', 'ad_negative_prompt': '', 'ad_confidence': 0.3, 'ad_mask_k_largest': 0, 'ad_mask_min_ratio': 0, 'ad_mask_max_ratio': 1, 'ad_x_offset': 0, 'ad_y_offset': 0, 'ad_dilate_erode': 4, 'ad_mask_merge_invert': 'None', 'ad_mask_blur': 4, 'ad_denoising_strength': 0.4, 'ad_inpaint_only_masked': True, 'ad_inpaint_only_masked_padding': 32, 'ad_use_inpaint_width_height': False, 'ad_inpaint_width': 512, 'ad_inpaint_height': 512, 'ad_use_steps': False, 'ad_steps': 28, 'ad_use_cfg_scale': False, 'ad_cfg_scale': 7, 'ad_use_checkpoint': False, 'ad_checkpoint': 'Use same checkpoint', 'ad_use_vae': False, 'ad_vae': 'Use same VAE', 'ad_use_sampler': False, 'ad_sampler': 'DPM++ 2M Karras', 'ad_use_noise_multiplier': False, 'ad_noise_multiplier': 1, 'ad_use_clip_skip': False, 'ad_clip_skip': 1, 'ad_restore_face': False, 'ad_controlnet_model': 'None', 'ad_controlnet_module': 'None', 'ad_controlnet_weight': 1, 'ad_controlnet_guidance_start': 0, 'ad_controlnet_guidance_end': 1, 'is_api': ()}, {'ad_model': 'None', 'ad_model_classes': '', 'ad_prompt': '', 'ad_negative_prompt': '', 'ad_confidence': 0.3, 'ad_mask_k_largest': 0, 'ad_mask_min_ratio': 0, 'ad_mask_max_ratio': 1, 'ad_x_offset': 0, 'ad_y_offset': 0, 'ad_dilate_erode': 4, 'ad_mask_merge_invert': 'None', 'ad_mask_blur': 4, 'ad_denoising_strength': 0.4, 'ad_inpaint_only_masked': True, 'ad_inpaint_only_masked_padding': 32, 'ad_use_inpaint_width_height': False, 'ad_inpaint_width': 512, 'ad_inpaint_height': 512, 'ad_use_steps': False, 'ad_steps': 28, 'ad_use_cfg_scale': False, 'ad_cfg_scale': 7, 'ad_use_checkpoint': False, 'ad_checkpoint': 'Use same checkpoint', 'ad_use_vae': False, 'ad_vae': 'Use same VAE', 'ad_use_sampler': False, 'ad_sampler': 'DPM++ 2M Karras', 'ad_use_noise_multiplier': False, 'ad_noise_multiplier': 1, 'ad_use_clip_skip': False, 'ad_clip_skip': 1, 'ad_restore_face': False, 'ad_controlnet_model': 'None', 'ad_controlnet_module': 'None', 'ad_controlnet_weight': 1, 'ad_controlnet_guidance_start': 0, 'ad_controlnet_guidance_end': 1, 'is_api': ()}, <scripts.animatediff_ui.AnimateDiffProcess object at 0x000001F9500268C0>, UiControlNetUnit(enabled=True, module='ip-adapter_clip_sd15', model='ip-adapter-plus_sd15 [836b5c2e]', weight=1, image={'image': array([[[ 99,  67,  45],

**
***
***         [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)}, resize_mode='Crop and Resize', low_vram=False, processor_res=512, threshold_a=-1, threshold_b=-1, guidance_start=0, guidance_end=1, pixel_perfect=False, control_mode='Balanced', inpaint_crop_input_image=False, hr_option='Both', save_detected_map=True, advanced_weighting=None), UiControlNetUnit(enabled=False, module='none', model='None', weight=1, image=None, resize_mode='Crop and Resize', low_vram=False, processor_res=-1, threshold_a=-1, threshold_b=-1, guidance_start=0, guidance_end=1, pixel_perfect=False, control_mode='Balanced', inpaint_crop_input_image=False, hr_option='Both', save_detected_map=True, advanced_weighting=None), UiControlNetUnit(enabled=False, module='none', model='None', weight=1, image=None, resize_mode='Crop and Resize', low_vram=False, processor_res=-1, threshold_a=-1, threshold_b=-1, guidance_start=0, guidance_end=1, pixel_perfect=False, control_mode='Balanced', inpaint_crop_input_image=False, hr_option='Both', save_detected_map=True, advanced_weighting=None), False, False, 'positive', 'comma', 0, False, False, 'start', '', 1, '', [], 0, '', [], 0, '', [], True, False, False, False, False, False, False, 0, False, None, None, False, None, None, False, None, None, False, 50) {}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\call_queue.py", line 57, in f
        res = list(func(*args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\call_queue.py", line 36, in f
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\txt2img.py", line 110, in txt2img
        processed = processing.process_images(p)
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\processing.py", line 785, in process_images
        res = process_images_inner(p)
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\batch_hijack.py", line 48, in processing_process_images_hijack
        return getattr(processing, '__controlnet_original_process_images_inner')(p, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\processing.py", line 1041, in process_images_inner
        devices.torch_gc()
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\devices.py", line 81, in torch_gc
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
      File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\memory.py", line 159, in empty_cache
        torch._C._cuda_emptyCache()
    RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
    Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.


---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py", line 488, in run_predict
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1431, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1103, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\gradio\utils.py", line 707, in wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\call_queue.py", line 77, in f
    devices.torch_gc()
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\webui\modules\devices.py", line 81, in torch_gc
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
  File "C:\Users\laugh\Downloads\sd.webui\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\memory.py", line 159, in empty_cache
    torch._C._cuda_emptyCache()
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

formating my computer, reinstall everything
Add '--skip-torch-cuda-test' to COMMANDLINE_ARGS